# Using an Apex Repeat in a VisualForce template, do not include particular data from that field

Tags: visualforce, apex

I have this visual force template that is creating a repeat on the below field. However I don't want it to include BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c = 'Email Sent' within the email body but to include all other actions. Would I need to develop a class to do this?

The visualforce template include the following:

```
<apex:repeat var="ih" value="{!relatedTo.BMCServiceDesk__Incident_Histories__r}">
<tr>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c} </b></td>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__date__c} </b></td>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__note__c} </b></td>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__userId__c} </b></td>
</tr>             
   </apex:repeat>
```

so my email looks like a tabled list (unfortunately i cannot post an image as I stackexchange will not let me)

Any help to remove this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sonya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<apex:repeat var="ih" value="{!relatedTo.BMCServiceDesk__Incident_Histories__r}">
    <tr>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c != 'Email Sent'}">
            <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c} </b></td>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__date__c} </b></td>
        <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__note__c} </b></td>
        <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__userId__c} </b></td>
    </tr>             
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: This is brilliant  -  Many thanks for your help. I change the above slightly so all columned data for any email sent action is removed to read: <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c != 'Email Sent'}">
            <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c} </b></td>
    
        <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__date__c} </b></td>
        <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__note__c} </b></td>
        <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__userId__c} </b></td>     </apex:outputPanel>

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude them using a conditionally rendered outputText element:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!items}" var="item">
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!item.BMCServiceDesk_actionId__c!='Email Sent'}"> ... </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```